# Python Popen freezing

Tags: python, powershell, subprocess, popen

For some reason Popen is failing to exit after a Powershell script is called and the output of the command is not dynamic.

Am I missing something in the code:

```
sCmd = "powershell -file somefile.ps1"
process = subprocess.Popen(sCmd.strip(), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:
    p = process.communicate()
    sys.stdout.write(p[0])
    sys.stderr.write(p[1])

    sys.stdout.flush()
    if(len(p[0]) == 0 and isinstance(process.poll(), int)):
        break

if(process.wait() != 0):
    os._exit(1)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using `os._exit()` instead of `sys.exit()` here?

Comment: No reason just force of habit I'm afraid. I know I should use the proper way of sys.exit() but the first example I ever used to exit a script was os._exit().

Comment: Well, using `_exit()` does *not* clean stuff up. It doesn't flush buffers, etc. You normally do want stuff to be cleaned up, so it's *much* better to call `sys.exit()` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verify that your powershell command is actually exiting correctly. A hung powershell process can easily be the cause of this.

Also you should not have the `shell=True`. It is a huge security risk. It could also be playing into why the process is hanging. If your powershell script won't run unless `shell=True` then fixing that would be a good place to focus.